# How to check for memory leak

Tags: c, memory-leaks

I have written an AI that uses maxmin algorithm to play a game.  Basically I am going 1 level  deep at this point.  I think I have a memory leak but I don't know how to trace it.  I used gdb but it wasn't helpful.

This is what is happening:

```
for (i = 0; i < max_legal; i++) {
    AddToBoard(legal_columns[i], legal_pieces[i]);
    val = Min(depth - 1, legal_columns[i]);
    RemoveFromBoard(legal_columns[i]);
    ......

}
```

- `legal_column` array has `{1,1,2,2...12,12}`
- `legal_pieces` array has `{1,3,1,3....1,3}`

When `i = 5`, legal pieces has `{1, 3, 1, 3, 1, 3, 97, 0 <repeats 11 times>}`.

I don't know where 97 and 0s are coming from.  Is it being overwritten? How do I find it?

Comment: Being overwritten doesn't necessarily mean there is a memory leak. Paste your full code please.

Answer (score 2):

You are using gdb so i assume you are running on a Linux machine. You can easily use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) to track memory leaks.

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes <your-app>
```

Comment: valgrind is testing you application in run time. If it says no errors were found it means no error were found in this specific execution. Can you please paste the command you ran with the valgrind output?

Comment: I see more errors.  This is the command I used.  valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./test.  Look at the message I am getting...
Invalid write of size 4
==19755==    at 0x400858: Max (aiV2.c:62)
==19755==    by 0x400772: MinMax (aiV2.c:24)
==19755==    by 0x400CBB: main (aiV2.c:175)
==19755==  Address 0x51b0368 is 4 bytes after a block of size 20 alloc'd
==19755==    at 0x4C267CC: calloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:467)
==19755==    by 0x4007E8: Max (aiV2.c:48)
==19755==    by 0x400772: MinMax (aiV2.c:24)
==19755==    by 0x400CBB: main (aiV2.c:175) What does that mean?

Comment: this is not a memory leak but you do access a memory that was not allocated  (buffer overflow).

Comment: I figured out what the problem was.  I was not callocing the array correctly, that's why it was overflowing.

Answer (score 0):

No. gdb won't be too helpful for tracing memory leaks. Consider using [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/), which will help you find memory leaks and other memory-related issues (eg. out of bounds accesses).

```
valgrind --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes ./your_app
```

Answer (score 0):

You may find helpful Dr.Memory. It is available for Windows and Linux.You can download it  [here](http://www.drmemory.org/)

It is a bit easier to use it.